# Closing all the modal bootstrap pop up in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to close all the modal pop up boxes when a user clicks on a close button of the final confirmation modal popup.

But the modal windows that are open do belong to different controllers. Here is the snippet :

```
function getQuickCasePopup($scope, $uibModal, $rootScope) {
    var templateUrl = BasePath + 'App/Transaction/Views/common/QuickCaseSearch.tpl.html';
    var controller = 'QuickCaseSearchCtrl';
    OpenModal($scope, $uibModal, null, templateUrl, controller, null, null, '', $rootScope);
}

function getAddCasePopup($scope, $uibModal, $rootScope) {
    var templateUrl = BasePath + 'App/Transaction/Views/common/CreateCase.tpl.html';
    var controller = 'AddCaseCtrl';
    OpenModal($scope, $uibModal, null, templateUrl, controller, null, null, '', $rootScope);
}

function getAdvanceCasePopup($scope, $uibModal, $rootScope) {
    var templateUrl = BasePath + 'App/Transaction/Views/common/AdvanceCaseSearch.tpl.html';
    var controller = 'AdvanceCaseCtrl';
    OpenModal($scope, $uibModal, null, templateUrl, controller,null, null, 'lg', $rootScope);
}

function OpenModal($scope, $uibModal, $stateParams, templ, ctrl, grid, row, size, $rootScope) {

    var CssClass = '';
    if (size === 'lg') {
        CssClass = 'app-modal-window';
    }

    var ModalInstance = ModalInstance || $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: templ,
        controller: ctrl,  // Logic in instantiated controller 
        windowClass: CssClass
    });
```

And the confirmation pop - up code looks like :

$("#iConfirmationModal").modal();

```
$("#iConfirmationModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

    //$(".app-modal-window").dialog("close"); //Did not work

    $state.go('transaction.search', {});
});
```

So I want to close all the modal pop-ups and then redirect . Can I achieve the same ?

Comment: Are these modals opened on top of each other, does second modal opens from within the first modal?

Comment: No these modals are separate.

Comment: you should create a factory to manage them in one place.

Answer (score 0):

The modal is a singleton object so you can call $scope.$close() and it all close all modal instance

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple options,

1. create a service which will manage all modal status.
2. Use $emit\$broadcast for notifications.
3. use third part libraries like [amplifyjs](http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/) and use there pub\sub operations.